# Rotate all packed bytes in AVX2 / AVX-512 register with minimum instruction code

Tags: byte, simd, bit-shift, avx2, avx512

Is it possible to do byte rotations using AVX2/AVX-512 instructions in less than 5 instructions?
Looking for answers in assembly code as I'm not familiar enough with intrinsics.

In AVX-512, direct rotations can be performed with a single instruction! Unfortunately WORD and BYTE data types are not covered. Shifts can be made down to WORD sizes, so that is a minimum of 3 instructions (2 shifts and 1 add/or/xor). The best I have come up with so far is a minimum of 5 instructions as listed below.

```
zmm0 is loaded with 64 different byte values
SL3 = memory location of 64 continuous bytes of f8h value (for masking)
SR5 = memory location of 64 continuous bytes of 07h value (for masking)

vpslld zmm1, zmm0, 3    ; shift DWORDS《 by 3 bits
vpandd zmm1, zmm1, SL3  ; clear low 3 bits, all bytes
vpsrl zmm2, zmm0, 5     ; shift DWORDS 》by 5 bits
vpandd zmm2, zmm2, SR5  ; clear high 5 bits, all bytes
vpord zmm1, zmm1, zmm2  ; combine left/right shifts for rotation result
```

Above is either a rotation left of 3 bits or a rotation right of 5 bits. And all 64 bytes yield correct results.

As I said, using WORD size (16 bits) a rotation is a minimum of 3 instructions. But due to needing 5 instructions for byte rotation in a zmm register, I only achieved a 50% performance increase going from 32 byte AVX2 implementation, to a 64 byte AVX-512 algorithm.

Comment: With AVX512 you can use [`vpternlog{d,q}`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpternlogd:vpternlogq) to combine the left-shift and right-shift result with a mask to the end-result.

Comment: Unfortunately `vpermt2b` is expensive (3 uops), so it's not worth doing a compare and byte-masked shuffles to implement an 8-bit lookup table.  So it is possible in 3 instructions with AVX-512VBMI, but the relevant metric is uops, not instructions.

Comment: For the AVX2 version where you can't use vpternlogd, you can use `vpand` / `vpandn` so you only need one mask.

Comment: VGF2P8AFFINEQB can implement *any* permutation of bits within a byte, so the byte rotate can be done in a single instruction with a suitable mask if you have that instruction (plus maybe one more to load the mask if you can't reuse it and can't use load-op).

Comment: @chtz, Thanks for the tip. I didn't really quite understand the workings of `vpternlog` very well until today. I had no idea of how powerful that instruction is. I had 10 places in my code where I reduced 5 instructions down to 3! My app run-time went from 141 seconds down to 100 seconds. Much appreciated.  :)

Comment: Clang actually automatically optimizes `(a & m) | (b & ~m)` to a `vpternlogq` instruction: https://godbolt.org/z/x71Pcs3hc (it also uses a broadcast-memory source).

Comment: @chtz, That's interesting. I went with `a&~c | (b&c)`. I only got into SIMD programming a year ago and it was a steep learning curve from the basic 8086 assembly I did in the mid 90s! From what I read, a single `vpternlog` instruction can replace up to 8 intructions. I'll have to delve into my code and see where else it can be utilised. Thanks again. How do I mark your comment as the answer?

Comment: Feel free to summarize all helpful comments to an answer (you can then accept this after some time).

Comment: @PeterCordes, In AVX2, to use `vpandn`, the bitmask would have to be placed in the 1st source operand for it to work. This means it has to be loaded into a register first. But that would add another instruction. Yes you would need only one bitmask in this case. Is this what you meant? I'm looking for a way to reduce the instructions from 5, to even 4 if possible.

Comment: Normally you're doing operations like this in a loop, so you can (and should) hoist the loads of the mask constants.  Like BeeOnRope, that's what I was assuming as the normal situation, especially with AVX-512 where you have 32 regs, meaning lots available to hold constants.  If you can't hoist the loads, then yeah I guess maybe use broadcast memory source operands for `vpandd` if front-end bandwidth is a key bottleneck (and load-port pressure isn't).  With broadcast sources, the constants only take 4 bytes each, so at least you're not using up two full cache lines.

Comment: I initially did try pre-loading all my masks into registers before entry into the loops in both AVX2 and AVX512 code. However there was no difference  in performance either way. I'm assuming this is because my code probably fits entirely in the cache.